# how can I override background-image of rich:inputNumberSpinner

Tags: jsf, richfaces, stylesheet

In richfaces has rich:inputNumberSpinner. It has two class following:

```
.rf-insp-inc {
    background-image: url("/test/facesx/rfRes/spinnerArrowTop.png?v=4.2.0.Final&db=eAH7z8DAAAAEAAEA&ln=org.richfaces.images");
}
and 
.rf-insp-dec {
    background-image: url("/test/facesx/rfRes/spinnerArrowBottom.png?v=4.2.0.Final&db=eAH7z8DAAAAEAAEA&ln=org.richfaces.images");
}
```

It's quite small if I test it on my Ipad. I want it's more bigger, so How can I override background-image of rich:inputNumberSpinner ?

I already put my background-image in my xhtml file but nothing change, what's wrong or missing ?

```
<style type="text/css">
     .rf-insp-inc{background-image: url(../../pics/icon_up.jpg);}
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: Try using firebug, to see if style is actually asigned to the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many useful tips on creating mobile applications with RichFaces 4 in [Getting Started With Mobile RichFaces](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/GettingStartedWithMobileRichFaces) document. You could use mobile-optimized skin (see step 3).

Another solution might be using !important in your CSS definition:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .rf-insp-inc{background-image: url(../../pics/icon_up.jpg) !important;}
</style>
```

Regards,
Palo